# How to install/download Java EE javadocs without glassfish?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, glassfish, javadoc

Specifically, I am on ubuntu 10.04. Is there a way to do it in synaptic?

Is there a sun/oracle url where I could download just the javadocs for Java EE. With Java SE, I am able to download only the javadocs. I do not wish to go thro with pointlessly installing a fish that I will never use just to get the javadocs.

I wish to avoid having a server's executables and files sitting pointlessly on my system whose existence I would forget. I am obsessive about having complete control of my system and knowledge of what software I have installed. Especially when I cannot see it on synaptic

I am not, have never been, and never will be, using glassfish. Are there any of you who would want to start a movement to stop sun/oracle forcing their fish down our throats? Or is there already such a movement? I just want the javadocs without the fish.

Comment: what about this [link](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=java_ee_sdk-6u2-docs-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer). you can download archive version of jee documents.

Comment: you can also download jee tutorial from this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=java_ee_6u1_docs-JPR@CDS-CDS_SMI

And just in case that link doesn't work, this is the page I found it on.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/apis-139520.html